# i setup email sent on status update (status is in tinyint format) i want to display Status as "in progress" not the tiny int how can i do that?

Tags: php, laravel

**/TemplateController**

```
    public function invoice_status_upadated(Request $request){ 

        $data= Invoice::find($request->id);
        $oldstatus = $data->status;
        $data->status = $request->status;

        $data->save();


        $email = Auth::user()->email;
        $status = $data->status;
        $id = $data->id;
        

        $msg = [
            'email' => $email,
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'oldstatus' => $oldstatus,
            'status' => $status,
            'id' => $id
                ];
                
        Mail::send('index.invStatusUpdate', $msg, function($msg) use($email){


        $msg->to($email)->subject('Invoice Status has been Changed');});

        return redirect('invoices');}
```

**Emails/invStatusUpdate.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <body>  
        <b>Hello {{$name}}<b><br>
        <p style="text-align:centre">Invoice ID: {{$id}} has been updated from {{$oldstatus}} to {{$status}} </p><br>
        <p>By {{$name}} </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Result in Email**

[image: Result in Email]

i want to change these marked tinyint (0 and 1) to "Pending","in Process"

**invoices/index.blade.php**

```
                        <td>
                          <form action="{{url('/invoice_status_upadated')}}" method="POST">
                          <input class="form-control" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{$inv['id']}}">
                            
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                              <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="status">
                            <option value="0" {{$inv->status == 0 ? 'selected':''}}>Pending </option>
                            <option value="1" {{$inv->status == 1 ? 'selected':''}}>In Process </option>
                            <option value="2" {{$inv->status == 2 ? 'selected':''}}>Completed </option>
                            <option value="3" {{$inv->status == 3 ? 'selected':''}}>Cancelled </option>
                              </select>
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-success">Update</button>
                        </div>
                          </form>
                        </td>
```

**Results on Status update page**

[image: Results on Status update page]

I just want to change the format in the email (0,1,2,3) to (pending, In process, Completed, Cancelled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can define an array like this

```
$statuses = [
   'Pending',
   'In process',
   'Completed',
   'Cancelled'
]
```

In `TemplateController`

```
$msg = [
   'email' => $email,
   'name' => Auth::user()->name,
   'oldstatus' => $statuses[$oldstatus],
   'status' => $statuses[$status],
   'id' => $id
];
```